# Finding $\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1 + \frac{2}{x} - x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I want to solve:

$$\int\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{x}-x} \mathrm{d}x $$

I don't know how to start, maybe I should use partial fraction?

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $x$ for a start...see what you get then

Comment: Any integrals of fractions of polynomials are easily evaluated. Just google it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multiply by $\frac{x}{x}$ to get a more recognisable form $$\int \frac{x}{2 + x - x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int \frac{-x}{(x+1)(x-2)} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Some partial fractions (I'll leave the gory details to you) yields $$-\frac{1}{3}\int \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{2}{x-2} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

which are easy logarithmic anti-derivatives.